# Reinforcement learning for predicting rotation between two images

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I have pairs of images randomly rotated with respect to each other. I want to predict the rotation angle. I don't know the true rotation angle, but I know that MSE between the two image after applying correct rotation should be minimized.

I could generate a training data with known rotations and train network.
But can we do this without training data, with MSE between original and rotated images as the loss function?

I tried to add a layer that applies predicted rotation to one input image and compares with the second input image. 
Alternatively, we could use custom loss function that does this, but it needs to take an input image and predicted rotation as input, instead of y_pred and y_true.

But I don't know how to do this in Keras. I am just a newbie so would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: Can't this be measured instead of predicted?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have knowledge about how neural networks work and some experience with python, I would suggest learning more about keras first. [This tutorial](https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python) is a great resource for getting started with keras and learning what it is capable of. That should get you started in the right direction, and then when you have more specific questions to ask we'll be able to help you more effectively.

Comment: Currently my NN takes 2 images and outputs a rotation angle. (1) I want to apply the predicted rotation to one of the input images and output the rotated image instead, so that the rms error between the second image and the rotated image can be used for training the network. How to do this in Keras? (2) Does training NN this way makes sense (without knowing the ground truth rotation)? I would appreciate your help.